# Did the change these names in newest version of fluent nhibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I updated to fluent nhibernate 1.2

and now some of my stuff does not work.

```
  public static PropertyBuilder NvarcharWithMaxSize(this PropertyBuilder map)
    {
        return map.Length(10000);
    }
```

I had to import a new using for PropertyBuilder(`using System.Reflection.Emit;`) what I have no clue if that is right.

Map.Length does not seem to exist either anymore I use to have (`using FluentNHibernate.Mapping.Builders;`).

Does anyone know what I need now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, version 1.2 got rid of the FluentNHibernate.Mapping.Builders namespace. See this very similar [question and answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621438/fluent-nhibernate-fluentnhibernate-mapping-builders-namespace)

Comment: I think I been going back and forth between PropertyPart and PropertyBuilder. Seems like everytime a new version comes out I have to fix these area up as this is like the 2 or 3rd time I done this.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at the built-in fluent config in NHibernate 3.0 is on my todo list now that 3.0 is working its way toward a stable release.